# How use Decimal function for decimal part of my Float python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write my float with scientific notation with `Decimal()` function.

For example, my number is `0.00045`

```py
from decimal import Decimal

def scientificNotationFloat(number):
   a = '%e' % Decimal(number)
   return a.split('e')[0].rstrip('0').rstrip('.') + 'e' + a.split('e')[1]
```

I don't know why, but this function return a positive power.
For follow our example, the result is `4.5e+03` but it's false because the good result is `4.5e-03`

Someone understands my mistake ? Thanks

Comment: which library you're working with?

Comment: I only use decimal library, I update my code with it.

Comment: You might want to try `to_sci_string()`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.to_sci_string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = '%e' % Decimal(number)
should be
a = '%.2E' % Decimal(number)
```

Use this program:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def scientificNotationFloat(number):
   a = '%e' % Decimal(number)
   return a.split('e')[0].rstrip('0').rstrip('.') + 'e' + a.split('e')[1]

def main():
    x = scientificNotationFloat(0.00045)
    print(x)
main()
```

This returns: `4.5e-04` for a test case of `0.00045`

Comment: Thank, this code allowed me to understand my mistake. I send ```00000000000006000``` not ```00000000000.006000```...